# Only reading additional content in a file

Tags: node.js, nodejs-stream

I'm working on a project which requires reading a log file, The log file can get massive, so I only want to read additional data added to the file and not the old data to avoid potential performance issues.

I tried fs.[createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#filehandlecreatereadstreamoptions) but it didn't seem to work:

code:

```js
let stream = fs.createReadStream(`/path/`, { autoClose: true, encoding: "utf-8" });

stream.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Loaded log file!");
})

stream.on("data", chunk => {

    // Data stream

});

stream.on("end", () => {
    stream.pause();

    console.log("ended");

    // Going thru the data

    setTimeout(() => {
        stream.resume();
        stream.read();
    }, 10000);

});
```

With that code, the "end" event only triggers once, although the stream is set to not close automatically, and no additional data is going thru.

Comment: You could save the line you last ended on and continue from there

Comment: @KyleRifqi How can I do that, cause as far as I know, if I'm reading the file again, it's going to use a lot of resources since I'm reading the entire file. which is not really ideal when you're reading it every 2 seconds. So if there's a way to start from a certain chunk using ReadStream that'd be exactly what i need!

Comment: after googling around it doesnt look like theres a way to specify a line to start on but there is the `start` options that you can use to skip over a number of bytes, so you could count the number of bytes youve read in a variable and use that as the start everytime you read the file again. this is just theoretical though, i have not tried this before.

Comment: @KyleRifqi Thanks, i will give it a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing a bit with the readStream and thanks to @KyleRifqi I was able to come up with this solution, storing the last amount of bytes and updating it everytime the stream ends.

```js
let lastBytes = 0;

let text = "";

let stream = fs.createReadStream(`/path/`, { autoClose: true, encoding: "utf-8", start: lastBytes });

stream.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Loaded log file!");
});

stream.on("data", chunk => {
    text += chunk;
});

stream.on("end", () => {
    let read = Buffer.byteLength(text, "utf-8");
    lastBytes += read;

    //Code here

});
```